# I changed package name, changed the app_name but installer still overwrites previous version

Tags: android, android-manifest

For diagnostic purposes, I am trying to install to an Android device two slightly different versions of the same app.

In order to accomplish that, I duplicated the project and changed the:

1. project name
2. package name
3. app name (as appears in the
   application's "android:label" in
   AndroidManifest.xml)

However, when I install the modified app, it **overwrites** the older app (with different project name, package name and app name).

Apparently, I am missing something else that needs to be changed, in order to let both projects exist on my Android phone side-by-side.

What is that "something else"?

Comment: Strange, for me it was always enough to change only package name to get 2 same apps installed

Comment: You can try to "Clean" the project (given that you use Eclipse), and then install it. This will regenerate R.java and might solve the problem.

Comment: Did you change the package name int he AndroidManifest?

Comment: @slund I changed the package name that prefixes the activity's android:name attribute, but I neglected to change the 'package' attribute in <manifest>. See my reply to @Stealth Rabbi. +1 to you too. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to change the package name text in the Android Manifest. If you change the package in the eclipse properties menu for the project, it doesn't change the actual AndroidManifest.xml.

**Edit:** The package name identified in the AndroidManifest.xml is the unique indetifier for the application, but I think, perhaps, not necessarily referencing the root package of your Android project's source code. I would think that it's best practice for them to be one in the same, but I could see where you could easily release an alternate version of an app (i.e. paid vs free) by changing the manifest application package, but not changing the underlying source code. Not saying that this is necessarily good practice, but seems like a possibility. Here is some more info :

http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/

Comment: OMG you are right. I changed the package name throughout the entire project (all .java files and layout XML files) but the package name in AndroidManifest.xml in both projects is still the same. This must be it. I'll test this & report back. Thanks!

Comment: Your Edit, accompanied by the link, was very educating to me. I am also able to confirm that the **Android** package name was the source of the problem. Answer accepted.

Comment: I have a duplicate project with a different <manifest package="_"> value and it is overwriting and being overwritten by the original project when installing to the emulator.

Comment: @Gimmethe411 how is it a duplicate project if you have a different manifest package? What does "being overwritten" mean?

Comment: @StealthRabbi I mean I changed the manifest package after duplicating it, but I was unable to have both applications installed on the device at the same time (because each time I would install 1, it would overwrite the other app). But after changing build.gradle applicationId field, I could install both apps on the device. So I think build.gradle applicationId is the correct thing to change, not manifest package.

Answer (score 2):

I had a duplicate project with a different manifest package="__" value and it was overwriting and being overwritten by the original project when installing to the emulator, so the other answer is not correct.

The correct field to change was in **build.gradle**:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "__" <--- change this value
```